# Call a function in code behind in aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRemove" runat="server" 
        Visible='<%# (string)Eval("GroupDescription") != "Default" %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Only problem is, it might not be 'Default'. Is there a way I could call a function like GetDefaultName in my code behind that would get it from the database?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: I learned C++ entirely by asking hundreds of questions on SO. The solutions are always to professional standards. Almost all 'tutorials' online use bad practices to get things done. That is why I do not try other ways because then my answer will be for a solution using bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will help you...

```
(string)Eval("GroupDescription") != "Default" ? GetDefaultName() : "Default"
```

in your class file write function like below..

```
protected string GetDefaultName()
{
    return "Your Default Name";
}
```

But i am not able to get **why you pass this to Visible Property....?**

Comment: Essentially, you can only edit a group if it is not the default, so I hide checkboxes if it is default.

Answer (score -1):

in your markup, call a server side function like this:

```
Visible = '<%# GenerateVisibility()  %>'
```

in your code behind, create a function like this:

```
protected bool GenerateVisilbity()
{
//other code here if needed... such as your GetDefaultName()
//do your logic and decide whether or not to return a "true" or "false" boolean

//sample return value below
return Eval("GetDefaultName");//must return boolean value

}
```

*edit to return boolean value, earlier i snagged it from my open project, was using it to return a custom javascript function as a string to bind to clientside event...

Comment: This won't work.  This syntax will expect GenerateVisibility to be a boolean method to fill in for the boolean property `Visible`.  you can run the Eval internally and have `GenerateVisibility` return the true/false value based on the eval.  But your method itself cannot return string.  It won't do a double-pass, first substituting the method and then running the substituted value; instead it will wait to execute the function until your databinding event and assume that function to return a boolean value.  Your core concept is correct.  Make the fix and then the answer is valid.